# How can I load CSV data into Memgraph Lab?

Tags: memgraphdb

I have a CSV file that represents relations between animals based on their taxonomy.

Columns are:

- Animal_1 (Latin name of the first animal)
- Animal_2 (Latin name of the second animal)
- Relation (Type of relation: e.g., "is related to", "is a subclass of", "is a predator of")
- Habitat (Where they are commonly found)
- Diet (What they typically eat)

My CSV file looks like this:

```
Animal_1,Animal_2,Relation,Habitat,Diet
Gallus gallus,Bos taurus,is a predator of,Mountainous,Omnivore
Cervus elaphus,Felis catus,is related to,Jungle,Omnivore
Panthera leo,Panthera leo,is a predator of,Forest,Herbivore
Cervus elaphus,Panthera leo,is a predator of,Savannah,Herbivore
Equus caballus,Equus caballus,is a predator of,Mountainous,Herbivore
Cervus elaphus,Bos taurus,is related to,Forest,Omnivore
Equus caballus,Felis catus,is a predator of,Grassland,Omnivore
Gallus gallus,Felis catus,is related to,Forest,Carnivore
Panthera leo,Felis catus,is a subclass of,Jungle,Carnivore
Felis catus,Canis lupus,is a predator of,Jungle,Carnivore
Equus caballus,Canis lupus,is related to,Mountainous,Herbivore
Canis lupus,Sus scrofa,is a predator of,Grassland,Herbivore
Bos taurus,Sus scrofa,is a predator of,Grassland,Herbivore
Panthera tigris,Bos taurus,is a predator of,Jungle,Omnivore
Bos taurus,Cervus elaphus,is related to,Mountainous,Carnivore
Equus caballus,Panthera leo,is related to,Domestic,Herbivore
Canis lupus,Bos taurus,is a predator of,Savannah,Carnivore
Sus scrofa,Equus caballus,is related to,Forest,Carnivore
Bos taurus,Bos taurus,is related to,Jungle,Herbivore
Panthera tigris,Felis catus,is a subclass of,Mountainous,Omnivore
```

I've downloaded Memgraph Lab 2.8.3. And I've tried to run the query:

```
    LOAD CSV FROM '/path-to-your-file.csv' WITH HEADER AS row
    CREATE (a:Animal {name: row.Animal_1, habitat: row.Habitat, diet: row.Diet}),
           (b:Animal {name: row.Animal_2, habitat: row.Habitat, diet: row.Diet})
    CREATE (a)-[:RELATION {type: row.Relation}]->(b);
```

and

```
    LOAD CSV FROM 'c:\temp\animal_relations.csv' WITH HEADER AS row
    CREATE (a:Animal {name: row.Animal_1, habitat: row.Habitat, diet: row.Diet}),
            (b:Animal {name: row.Animal_2, habitat: row.Habitat, diet: row.Diet})
    CREATE (a)-[:RELATION {type: row.Relation}]->(b)
```

But all that I get are error that file is not there

[Error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWhfH.png)

[Error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEIHz.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks that your path is broken. Your prompt reveals that you are using Windows. I presume that you are using Docker installation of Memgraph. You can either [copy the file to your Docker container](https://memgraph.com/docs/getting-started/first-steps-with-docker#copy-files-from-and-to-a-docker-container) and then reference it in `LOAD CSV` or you can use remote server.

You can import CSV data from a remote server into Memgraph. The `LOAD CSV` clause in Memgraph allows you to load data from a CSV file located either on your local file system or over the network. If you are using `http://`, `https://`, or `ftp://`, the CSV file will be fetched over the network.

Here is the syntax for the `LOAD CSV` clause:

```
LOAD CSV FROM <csv-location> ( WITH | NO ) HEADER [IGNORE BAD] [DELIMITER <delimiter-string>] [QUOTE <quote-string>] [NULLIF <nullif-string>] AS <variable-name>
```

In this syntax, `<csv-location>` is a string of the location to the CSV file. If you are using a URL protocol, it refers to a remote file location.